# Pre-1960s novel where Earth humans are kidnapped by psychics from another planet

Tags: story-identification, novel

Earth and an Earth-like planet with human inhabitant, the people of which have mental powers that enable them to control people. Their society is ranked by the number of people they can control. The top ranking leaders are known as 70's (80's?) because they can control up to 80 people. Ranking is done by challenging people (like judo).

People on Earth start to disappear and it is thought that someone is kidnapping them and taking them to the other planet. Since Earth people have no mental powers, it is thought that a limitless number could be controlled as slaves.

A joint investigation is agreed and an Earth detective is partnered with a "40" from the other planet. In the end a rogue "70" was found to be the person.

It's not *Caves of Steel* since that's about robots.

Comment: I second Valorum's posting. From having read the novel, the description from Graham matches perfectly.

Comment: possibly the same as possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8904/can-you-identify-this-novel-about-mind-control-where-everyone-wears-catsuits (which has an accepted answer)

Comment: THANK YOU ALL. sounds like my book dated 1967. I was 11 at the time !!! Have ordered a second hand copy from the USA !! Thank you all for taking the time to help. you have part a big smile on my face !! :)